# Does Running Spring Boot Microservices in Production requires a license for the embedded Tomcat server for big enterprises?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, production, enterprise

We have built some Microservices with Spring Boot (Using Spring Cloud Dependencies). Now as we know Spring Boot comes with an embedded Tomcat Server. Can it be deployed to production with the same embedded Tomcat Server. If we are running this in production for an big enterprise do we need a separate Tomcat license for these embedded Tomcat servers?

Comment: The Tomcat license is already Apache 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use microservices architecture,  embedded tomcat is enough even in production.

Tomcat is open source, so you don't need lisences.